# Invalid date error with django DateField using generic UpdateView and bootstrap_datepicker_plus

Tags: django, bootstrap-5, django-crispy-forms

Django noob but been wrangling with this for a while.

When attempting to update or create a new ticket on my dev server I encounter an error beneath the field stating 'Enter a valid date.'.

The relevant details

models.py

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
     date_of_complaint = models.DateField()
```

ticket_new.html template

```
<!--templates/ticket_edit-->
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Edit</h1>
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.media }}
  {{ form|crispy }}
  <button class="btn btn-info ml-2" type="submit">Update</button>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

views.py

```
class TicketCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Ticket
    template_name = "ticket_new.html"
    fields = (
        "title",
        "date_of_complaint",
        "author",
        "customer",
        "description",
        "account_manager",
    )

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
    
    def get_form(self):
        form = super().get_form()
        form.fields["date_of_complaint"].widget = DateTimePickerInput()
        return form
```

settings.py

I believe the root of the issue is that the field was formerly a DateTimeField before I realized I did not want the time, only the date. I changed the model to DateTime and ran makemigrations and migrate, then changed the settings of bootstrap date picker plus to only include mm/dd/yyyy, but when I click on a date within the widget it still brings a timestamp.

settings.py

```
BOOTSTRAP_DATEPICKER_PLUS = {
    "options":{
        "showTodayButton": True,
    },
    "variant_options": {
        "date": {
            "format": "MM/DD/YYYY",
        },
    }
}
```

I thought adding settings to configure the format would fix the issue but it has not.